# How to enable USB debugging on Android Virtual Device (AVD) from ADB commands and by Java program?

Tags: java, android, appium, adb

I am working on automating an Android app using Appium. My aim is to create and launch AVD programmatically. Also, I need to enable the USB debugging on the created AVD.
Is there any way from ADB commands and Java program to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to enable usb debugging on AVD, device should be visible by default. AVDs from Google work this way no idea about other emulators, but I don't think you can enable usb debug from java program on PC.

Comment: USB debugging needs to be enabled for Appium to run tests on that device.

Comment: Appium uses adb afaik and it should work without any need to enable usb debuging on emulated Android. Also, you asked wrong question - you can't enable usb debugging if it's disabled, because with usb debugging disabled there's no any commucation with device. AVD should come with debuggin enabled by defualt.

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked. Appium is working without manually enabling usb debugging when we create it.